# Make certain parts of svg file clickable - ALSO LET IT RESIZE FLUTTER

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image, dart

I want to make certain parts of an image in flutter clickable, while also allowing the image to be resizable and still be clickable. How would I do that? This is the image I want clickable in certain areas.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1095483953504321678/1116411045536342027/mesh_back.png

As you can see, I want to have each muscle clickable. Just log the name of the muscle when it gets clicked - you don't have to do everything, you can just do one - for example, make the shoulder clicklable and tell me what each part of the code does and I can do the rest. Thank you SOSOSOSOOSOS much!!!

Comment: you need to create a custom `ShapeBorder` - it then can be used with `Material` widget to give a non rectangular shape - most likely the easiest way is to parse some svg file which defines all the body parts